# How to emit socket to specific socket connection?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In my node app,

```
socket.on('test', function (req) {
   controller.test(socket, req, 'test');
})
```

**This way I store all users socket connections in server...**

```
var userSockets = []; //Used to store all connected users data.

userSockets[user.id] = socket;  // Storing whole socket object.
// E.x: userSockets[14] = socket; // Stored like this.
```

**Function to get all socket data**

```
getUserSocket() {
    return userSockets;
}
```

**Now I need to emit to the specific socket, I have tried this but I got an error.**

```
let allUserSocketListData = databaseHelper.getUserSocket();

allUserSocketListData[result.data[0].id].emit('response' , data);
// E.x: allUserSocketListData[14].emit('response' , data);
```

**Error:**

```
.emit() is not a function.
```

**Update**

I have one function in that I'm storing all user's socket data.

```
validateUser(user, socket) {
    ...  // My some code
    userSockets[user.id] = socket;                            
}
```

Comment: Are You sure that `result.data[0].id` is not empty? Also show us whole scope of code how You store sockets when new connection

Comment: Yes, it's not empty. I have also console that, And I got data also in that.

Comment: ok when You get user object? `userSockets[user.id] = socket` is not obvious

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: ))) Sachin, how can You tell me that `validateUser` called correctly? You did not get my question. Please explain from where this `user` object comes from?

Comment: @num8er `validateUser` called correctly, I have checked it. In this function, I'm executing query to fetch user data. The return data from db, I'm storing user's data in `user` object.

Comment: Sachin, again, show the code when You call validateUser? I understand that You're getting it from db. But when? How Your app knows that `user` is correct user? During socket handshake? Or it sends special cookie after socket connection which You're using to get user? Or You use `socketio-auth` package?

Comment: io.sockets.connected[allUserSocketListData[result.data[0].id]].emit("response", data);

Comment: @ShubhamSharma `allUserSocketListData[result.data[0].id]` is already a socket

Comment: `emit() is not a function` means that object has `emit` key but it's not a function. That's why I'm saying show us full code. Cause it's possible that You're not saving socket object, but something different that also has emit field.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces and rooms were build for that specific reason, but when you need something handy without extra code, sending emits directly can do job.
Here's a quick approach:
1: Your connection event should store the socket ID and not the whole object

```
let socketIds = []
socketServer.on("connection",(socket)=>{
    socketIds.push(socket.id)
    socket.emit("message", "hey")
})
```

2: Now if you want to send something on the **first client** only for example, you should first check if it's already registered and proceed with the emit.

```
if (socketServer.sockets.connected.hasOwnProperty(socketIds[0])){
    socketServer.sockets.connected[socketIds[0]].emit("message", "hey again")
} else {
    console.error("Error: Wrong Id")
}
```

Comment: it's not a solution to his question.

Comment: @num8er I posted the logic and based on that he could emit to any client he wants. For example he could store an array of objects that hold any kind of values and push to `socketIds` something like `socketIds.push({clientusername: "user1", secretId: "xxxxxxx", socketId:socket.id})` and send using `socket.sockets.connected[socketsIds.filter(u=>u.clientusername==="user1")[0].socketId]`. He could also store the whole object and fetch it using a for loop using `socket.id` and ``socketServer.sockets.connected` to emit.

Comment: there is no need to store extra sensitive data in `socketIds` when it's not used anywhere, You're consuming extra memory for storing useless data. He already keeps an object that holds `user.id => socket` reference. So he has issue when he is not getting socket from that object. So that's why in comments I'm asking him to give more details.